# Access variables globally in onPreDraw() method

Tags: java, android

I want use variable finalHeight and finalWidth outside the method however i can not use it. It always give me 0 as value. How can i get the exact value.

```
        int finalHeight, finalWidth;
        iv = (imageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
            finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
            Log.d("height", "Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);

            return true;
        }
    });
        Log.d("Height1",Integer.toString(finalHeight));
```

Inside onPreDraw method i get (728, 528). However outside loop it is giving 0.
How can use finalHeight and finalWidth globally in my other functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "globally"? Just other functions within this class, or even wider scope?

Comment: yes just other functions within this class

Comment: try to override `Activity#onWindowFocusChanged`

Comment: can u just explain a little bit how should i override, i am not really good in android :)

Comment: it has nothing to do with android: it is about java and method overriding